# I can't get user input from the test class in main

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        test[] t = new test[3];
        for (int i = 0;i<t.length;i++)
        {

            System.out.println("\nEnter name "+(i+1)+" : ");
            t[i].setName(sc.next());
            System.out.println("Enter studentID : ");
            t[i].setStudenid(sc.next());
            System.out.println("Enter phone number : ");
            t[i].setPhonenumber(sc.nextInt());
        }

        for (int i = 0;i<t.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Name "+(i+1)+" : "+t[i].getName());
            System.out.println("Student ID  : "+t[i].getStudenid());
            System.out.println("Phone number : "+t[i].getStudenid());
        }


    }
}
```

```
public class test {

    private String name ;
    private String studenid;
    private int phonenumber;

    public test(String name, String studenid, int phonenumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.studenid = studenid;
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStudenid() {
        return studenid;
    }

    public void setStudenid(String studenid) {
        this.studenid = studenid;
    }

    public int getPhonenumber() {
        return phonenumber;
    }

    public void setPhonenumber(int phonenumber) {
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    }
}
```

when i run, it says
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "trying.test.setName(String)" because "t[i]" is null
at trying.Main.main(Main.java:14)
i want to get user input for test class and it is array.
I already try many solution but still the same

Comment: Add 't[i] = new test(null, null, 0);' after the first loop in main so the object test exists in the array.

Comment: tqvm. it works perfectly